# How can I share my current location with my friends?

Tags: location-services

Can I use my Windows Phone to allow my friends to see my current location?

Is it possible without having to explicitly share using an application?

How to friends get to access the information?  Can I see the location of my friends on my phone?

Is there any Google Latitude like functionality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this. The only thing that's built-in that I can think of is the "locate my phone" feature that lets you log into www.live.com and track the location of your phone (useful if you lose it or it gets stolen). However, if you want to share your location with your friends, you will have to use an app and external service for this.

You mention Google Latitude. Although Google doesn't currently have an official Google Latitude client for Windows Phone (or really, much of an app for anything on Windows Phone...), there are third-party options. One that I'm particularly fond of is [gMaps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/c83aade5-5191-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8) (or its ad-supported [free version](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/7b8bedd5-4368-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8)). There are other clients as well, such as [Latitude Auto-Update](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/368ca0b8-4dcf-47d4-ad7f-08cee47e8f12) and [Latitude for WP7](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/d845515b-e653-400d-8ea8-9a3c54febe9e).

If you are on AT&T, there is the [AT&T Family Map](https://familymap.wireless.att.com/finder-att-family/supportedPhones.htm) service. There are also other apps that have their own spin on finding people by tracking their location, like [Who's Near Me LIVE](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/apps/e0b331a9-85e8-df11-9264-00237de2db9e).

In all, you'll have to find an app to do what you want to do. Windows Phone doesn't support this as built-in functionality, at this time.

Comment: I think kris' answer would be considered built in functionality.  It's the way I do it.

Answer (score 14):

When sending an sms hit the paperclip icon under the message window and click 'my location'. Send.

Boom.

Comment: This is actually the right answer.  No additional app needed.  Works out of box.  Platform agnostic.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows Phone 8 this is a feature of the shared chat in a Room. So you could invite all your friends (which should also have a Windows Phone 8, or this will not work) and send your location in the shared Room chat window.

Answer (score 4):

There's a free app called [**Locate Me**](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/aaa64d71-1250-4161-924b-8d6052eb75dc) (there are two other apps with the same name) which I have found useful to quickly email my location to another person.  You can also use it to post to social networking sites.

[image: Locate Me]

Answer (score 2):

You can share your location via HERE maps. To do so, make a route to a location very close to you (1-2m off). Then at the bottom of the route description, tap the share-icon [image]. You can send your location via Email, SMS or Third-Party apps. Your friends will get a link to a map via the HERE website.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a free location sharing tool for MOBILE. Take a look I think it is exactly what you are looking for. http://geo.to

Comment: The question was whether there was anything "built in" - not sure how your solution qualifies for that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Nokia Beamer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=b5511af6-cbd0-4945-9bf6-30cf0582043f) app (not to be confused with PhotoBeamer) can be used to share your location.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest update (version 2.22.0.110), Skype on Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 supports location sharing. Simply tap the "+" icon in a chat and select "Share location". You'll be asked to turn on access to location services, after which Skype will post a link to your current location on Bing Maps.

More at the Skype blog: [Location Sharing comes to Skype for Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/09/10/location-sharing-comes-to-skype-for-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-phone-8)